# Specify @XmlJavaTypeAdapter class via bindings file?

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I have a 3rd party interface that supplies xsd files that matches their API. Some of their mappings are not quite Java, the usual boolean as 0 & 1 :-(

I'd like to use a bindings file to specify the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter class for my BooleanAdapter, but so far no joy.

The bindings file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="GetUserDetailsResponse.xsd" node="/xs:schema" >
        <jaxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asWordSeparator" >
            <jaxb:serializable uid="1" />
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.Boolean" xmlType="xs:boolean"
printMethod="mumble.bindings.BooleanAdapter.marshall" 
parseMethod="mumble.bindings.BooleanAdapter.unmarshall" />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And since I'm using maven the relevant bit from the POM:

```xml
<strict>false</strict>
<extension>true</extension>
<verbose>true</verbose>
<enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>
<enableAsyncMapping>false</enableAsyncMapping>
```

I've toggled enableWrapperStyle and no change

What I end-up with is a generated Adapter of the wrong type:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
public class Adapter1
    extends XmlAdapter<String, Boolean>{
    public Boolean unmarshal(String value) {
        return (mumble.bindings.BooleanAdapter.unmarshall(value));
    }

    public String marshal(Boolean value) {
        return (mumble.bindings.BooleanAdapter.marshall(value));
    }
}
```

Is there some bindings file magic I can use to get rid of the generated wrapper and use the BooleanAdapter directly?

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html

Comment: No, I've already looked at that, it's not what I want. I could probably live with Adapter1 if I could force it convert int <--> boolean rather than string <--> boolean but the unnecessary extra layer of Adapter would ultimately irritate me. Thanks.

Comment: see this: http://adventuresintechology.blogspot.ca/2012/04/binding-custom-xmljavatypeadapter-to.html. I was able to implement exactly what you are asking here with the help of this post.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `<xjc:javaType>` in your binding config instead of `<jaxb:javaType>`.
For example:

```
<xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Boolean" xmlType="xs:boolean"
              adapter="mumble.bindings.BooleanAdapter"/>
```

I understand I'm answering to an old question, but I don't have enough reputation to write a comment.

Comment: `I understand I'm answering to an old question, but I don't have enough reputation to write a comment.` You aren't supposed to answer in comments anyways! :)

Comment: does not works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037803/why-jaxb-adapter-annotation-is-not-added-to-the-proxy-classes

Answer (score 4):

*It's a super late response, I realize, but even [mvv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676664/mvv)'s response left me struggling to totally grasp what I was doing and where in the structure the new element fit, so I wanted to add some further detail for anyone coming across this later.*

Per [mvv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676664/mvv), the easiest answer is to change to using the `xjc:javaType`. See [jaxb customization](https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#javaType) for the detailed documentation on using `xjc:javaType`.

You'll also need to change your custom adapter (BooleanAdapter) to implement the XmlAdapter interface.

Ultimately, your binding would instead look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="GetUserDetailsResponse.xsd" node="/xs:schema" >
        <jaxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asWordSeparator" >
            <jaxb:serializable uid="1" />
            <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Boolean" xmlType="xs:boolean"
                  adapter="mumble.bindings.BooleanAdapter" />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: jenrmagas: Do you know by any chance how to have adapter do the marshalling and unmarshalling for java.util.List? Notice that <xjc:javaType> accepts xmlType="xyz", and "lists" in Schema are represented with maxOccurance=unbounded rather than an actual Schema type.

Comment: hm.. does not works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037803/why-jaxb-adapter-annotation-is-not-added-to-the-proxy-classes